# Java BufferedReader special char sometimes not identified

Tags: java, utf-8, bufferedreader

I implemented a BufferedReader to read a textfile (MultipartFormdata from a UI, Restbased) for my application:

```
if (input == null || input.getParts() == null || input.getParts().isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Multipart request is empty");
    }

    try {
        InputStream result;
        if (input.getParts().size() == 1) {
            InputPart filePart = input.getParts().iterator().next();
            MultivaluedMap<String, String> header = filePart.getHeaders();
            filename = ImportHelperService.getFileName(header);
            result = filePart.getBody(InputStream.class, null);
        } else {
            result = input.getFormDataPart("file", InputStream.class, null);
        }

        if (result == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't find a valid 'file' part in the multipart request");
        }

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(result, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        String temp ="";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((temp = in.readLine()) != null) {
                if(!sb.toString().equals(""))
                    sb.append("\n");
            sb.append(temp);
        }
        in.close();
        fileString = sb.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error while reading multipart request", e);
    }
```

In my Input there is sometimes a special character **µ** , but my BufferedReader cant handle it. The input for this is a black square with a ?. Can someone help me?
I tried to copy this µ by hand into my textfile, then the µ is identified. But if we get this µ in a textfile by our clients, the µ is the ?. How can I handle this?

Comment: You need to specify the correct encoding when you create the `InputStreamReader`.  You're specifying `UTF-8` and the file is probably some other format.

Comment: The UI is sending via AJAX wit charset-utf8

Comment: Clearly it isn't.  Can you post the raw bytes of a message with the problem?  (Edit: it's possible that the UI is supposed to send UTF-8 but someone else has messed-up and is sending data in the wrong encoding.)

Comment: [1] What is the actual character giving the problem? Is it ['MICRO SIGN' U+00B5](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00b5/index.htm) or ['GREEK SMALL LETTER MU' U+03BC](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/03bc/index.htm)? Both are rendered as **µ**. [2] Clarify what you mean by _"my BufferedReader cant handle it"_. That is far too vague; describe precisely what actually happens.

Comment: I guess it stands for micro sign, cause its a scientist file. But I opened that file with notepad++ and the encoding is ANSI ! Guess here is the problem. If my BufferedReader is using UTF-8, there are decodeerrors. TY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are your BufferedReader with the same Charset of your file? For example if your file is written in UTF-8, your BufferedReader must be configured with UTF-8 charset.

Comment: The UI is sending me a file with charset-utf8

Comment: Two other checks. 1- Your file file is truly saving using UTF-8? 2- Your BufferedReader is using UTF-8?

Comment: The File was safed in ANSI and not in UTF-8.